# Less conditions for limit of $f\circ g$ , with peculiar def. of limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

The definition of limit I'm using is the following:

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=b$
>
> iff
>
> $a$ is limit point of the domain of $f$ and
>   $\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}\forall_x(x\in D \land
>  |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-b|<\epsilon)$, where $D$ is the domain of $f$

Using this definition, am I correct in saying that for the limit of $f\circ g$ to exist, it's enough both functions to have the usual limits, i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=b$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow b}f(x)=c$, and $a$ be a limit point of the domain of $f\circ g$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these conditions are *sufficient*, just check the definition.

We already know that $a$ is a limit point of the domain of $f\circ g$. Then it is also a limit point of the domain of $g$ (which cannot be smaller than the domain of $f\circ g$ - and apart from that observation: We are given that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=b$, so $a$ must be a limit point of $\operatorname{dom}(g)$).

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We want to find $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f\circ g)$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|f(g(x))-c|<\epsilon$.
As we are given that $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=c$, we can find at least some $\delta_f>0$ such that $|f(x)-c|<\epsilon$ holds for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$ with $|x-b|<\delta_f$.
As $\delta_f>0$, we conclude from the given $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=b$ that (using $\delta_f$ as $\epsilon$) there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(g)$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|g(x)-b|<\delta_f$.
To summarize,
$$\tag1\forall x\colon\quad x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)\land |x-b|<\delta_f\implies |f(x)-c|<\epsilon $$
$$\tag2\forall x\colon\quad x\in\operatorname{dom}(g)\land |x-a|<\delta\implies |g(x)-b|<\delta_f$$

This $\delta$ is what we were looking for: Let $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f\circ g)$ with $|x-a|<\delta$. Then in particular $x\in\operatorname{dom}(g)$ and hence $|g(x)-b|<\delta_f$ by $(2)$. Moreover, $g(x)\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$ so that $|f(g(x))-c|<\epsilon$ by $(1)$, as desired.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. By the way, which definition of limit is more useful in the long term: this, or the one with the punctured neighbourhood?